# How to pass a SQLAlchemy ORM model to Python Generic[T] class

Tags: python, generics, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create an entity architecture with SQLAlchemy and python Generics, i.e  Model -> Repository -> API

I have the following User model:

```
class User(db.Model):
  id
  username
  email
  ...
```

The following Repository code:

```
class UserRepository(Repository[User]):
  pass
```

I'm trying to find a way that I could "access" the User model from within the **Repository** base class, something like:

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class Repository(Generic[T]):

  @staticmethod
  def get(id) -> T:
    return T.query.filter(...)
```

Tried also going via `db.session.query(...)` without success.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it with the help of class variables

```
class XRepository(BaseRepository):
  model = X


class YRepository(BaseRepository):
  model = Y
```

```
class BaseRepository:

  @classmethod
  def get(cls):
    return cls.model.query.filter(...)
```